# string/arrays parameters help in C programming

Tags: c, string, char, printf, scanf

So when I try to print out two strings, the first string doesnt print out. It
appears as a space. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char noun[10];   
    char temp[10];   // Stores temporary word entered by user 

    printf("Please enter word: "); 
    scanf("%s", noun); 

    temp[10] = noun[10];     
    pluralize(noun);     // Function  adds 's' to scanned word

    printf("The word changes from  %s to %s", temp, noun);

    return 0;
}
```

So if I type in 'cat', the output comes out as:

```
The word changes from  to cats
```

I need the original word to appear, not a space as in:

```
The word changes from cat to cats
```

Comment: [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) looks like it may be helpful here.

Comment: Please share the definition of `pluralize`.

Comment: `temp[10] = noun[10]; ` that's two out of bounds array accesses in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Char array `temp[]` is 10 `char`s long, starting with `temp[0]` up to `temp[9]`. That said, `temp[10]` is out of array's bounds, thus invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Same goes for `noun[10]`.

In order to copy a string to another, you can use [`strcpy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 temp[10] = noun[10];
```

Here you are copying 10th element of noun array into 10th element of temp array,accessing this location will result in undefined behavior

With

```
strcpy(temp,noun);
```

Comment: @  juanchopanza you can help by providing the correct statement.Did you read the whole statement?

Comment: Just read my comment to the question, or the most up-voted answer.

Comment: With `noun[10]` you can access only `0 to 9`. so `noun[10]` is `out of bounds access`

Comment: Thats what I have mentioned in my comment,please scroll.Compiler will generate the code for accessing 10th location of the array.It will not give error.

Comment: @ juanchopanza I have mentioned this is undefined behavior in comment it selt,Copying it here again for you "/Here you are copying 10th element of noun array into 10th element of temp array,accessing this location will result in undefined behavior"

Comment: "Here you are copying 10th element of noun array into 10th element of temp array" that's wrong. It isn't the 10th element. But it would help if you put explanations in the answer's text, not in a very ling inline code comment.

Comment: @juanchopanza:You can always do Out of bound array access in 'C' if you are totally aware of what are you doing.In resource critical embedded systems this approach is sometimes used for speed,code optimization(NOT ADVISED THOUGH).